# How to convert a .mat file to mne raw file?

Tags: python, mne-python

I tried to convert a 'BCICIV_calib_ds1d.mat' file to a .mne raw file using the `mne.io.RawArray()` function.

First, I read the .mat file using the `scipy.io.loadmat()` function:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat(filepath)
```

to get a dictionary. Then, convert the dictionary to a `np.array` by using

```
dat = list(data.items())
np_arr = np.array(dat)
```

Then, I declared 'info' using the `mne.info()` function with channel names and sampling frequency. And then call

```
raw = mne.io.RawArray(np_arr,info)
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b04e9a0d29d1> in <module>()
      2 np_arr = np.array(np_arr)
      3 
----> 4 raw = mne.io.RawArray(np_arr,info)

<decorator-gen-210> in __init__(self, data, info, first_samp, copy, verbose)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    134 
    135     """
--> 136     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    137 
    138 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '__header__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get only the data not the entire information so look for the key corresponding to data with a 2d to 3d data array that contains the time,samples,values etc and then take only that chunk and pass it to this function
I did it this way when I was getting the error

```html
np_arr = np.array(mat_data['EEG']['data'])
np_arr=np_arr.reshape(99,64,640)
raw = mne.EpochsArray(np_arr,info)
```

Comment: Your code snippet actually suggests that the data are in the EEGLAB format, which can be read into mne-python with `mne.io.read_raw_eeglab` or `mne.io.read_epochs_eeglab` .